# How to pass each line in a file as argument to a script?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp

Iam working on a project which connect between a remote and pull files and do some work with these files.While pulling the files there are several directories in the remote,so pulling each folder is time taking.So is there any command which can be used in the script written below so it can automatically pull all files in the folders.

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

ssh someName@192.168.X.X 'ls SomeFolder/SomeSubFolder' > folders.txt

cat folders.txt
echo "Enter the folder name "
read folder_name

scp -r someName@192.168.X.X:SomeFolder/SomeSubFolder/$folder_name/ $folder_name/

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    # single filename is in $file
    python scanner_new.py /home/nsadmin/Kiran/bash_script_run_files/"$file"
done < <(find "$folder_name" -type f -print0)
rm -rf $folder_name
```

Here everytime the script asks for the folder_name and when user enters the folder_name.The script goes to remote and bring files and do some operation.Now First time when it goes to remote it brings `folders.txt file`. So it contains all the folders names.So with using these names to pass as arguments to the `python scanner.py $file_name`.

Folders.txt looks like this

```
2016_9_25
2016_9_26
2016_9_27
2016_9_28
2016_9_29
2016_9_30
2016_9_7
2016_9_9
```

Comment: Huh?  The `import os` line is Python but everything else before and after is a (crude) Bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the txt file with Python :

```
from os import path

def do_stuff_with_folder(folder_name):
  folder_name = folder_name.strip()
  script_name = path.join("/home/nsadmin/Kiran/bash_script_run_files/", folder_name)
  if path.exists(folder_name):
    print "Do stuff with folder %s" % folder_name
    # do stuff with folder_name here
  else:
    print "Warning : %s not here" % folder_name

with open('folders.txt') as folder_names:
  for folder_name in folder_names:
    do_stuff_with_folder(folder_name)
```

The loop is now inside Python, you'd just need to call the above script :

```
python scanner_new.py
```